# Get links from RSS feed

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to append all links in the RSS feed of this [Google News page](https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=best-refrigerator-2021&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en) using Beautiful Soup. I'm probably doing too much, but I can't seem to do it with this loop that iterates through a list of search terms for which I want to scrape Google News.

```
for t in terms:
    raw_url = "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=" + t + "&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen"
    url = raw_url.replace(" ","-")
    req = Request(url)
    html_page = urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
    links = []
    links.append(re.findall("href=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\']", str(html_page), flags=0))
    print(links)
```

The list comes up empty every time. My regex is probably off...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let BeautifulSoup help you by extracting all of the `<item>` tags, but because the link is not part of an embedded tag, you need to do the rest by hand.  This does what you want, I think.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

terms = ['abercrombie']

for t in terms:
    url = f"https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={t}&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen"
    html_page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.text, "lxml")
    for item in soup.find_all("item"):
        link= str(item)
        i = link.find("<link/>")
        j = link.find("<guid")
        print( link[i+7:j] )
```